# How to proxy request to a given domain name to a local port?

Tags: networking, macos

I want to make it so that when I perform a request to `test.com`, it will be redirected to `localhost:3001`.

How can this be done in MacOS?

I know that there is `/etc/hosts` but it's only concerned with domain names, not with ports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: no.
But you can use local IP-adresses instead of the localhost. (Which refers to the local adresses as you can see from the file itself.)

There may be a solution over on github, which may work (didn't try or build it myself.)

https://gist.github.com/exupero/3228103